# Parse JSON object with Node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I have a little node application that runs and gets stats from an httpprovider

Its returning the value every second in this format:

```
{ WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_CURRENT: 21,
  WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_TOTAL: 4879,
  WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_IN: 303242,
  WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_OUT: 96372 }
```

but I need it to be returning in a different format, exactly like this:

```
WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_CURRENT 21 Rem-East-v4-Edge-1
WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_TOTAL 4879 Rem-East-v4-Edge-1
WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_IN 303242 Rem-East-v4-Edge-1
WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_OUT 96372 Rem-East-v4-Edge-1
```

How would I accomplish this?

Here is my Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Requires.
// request, jsdom, optimist, all of which can be install with npm.

// NOTE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Uses jsdom 0.2.13, 0.2.14 has a bug
// https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/436
// Install w/ npm via `npm install jsdom@0.2.13`
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Require modules.
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    argv = require('optimist').argv;

// Make sure that at least the --uri argument was passed.
if (argv.uri.length == 0) {
  console.log('URI Required! Script should be called with one argument which is the URI of the connectioncounts HTTP provider to query.');
  return;
}

/**
 *
 */
var Collector = {
  stats: {},
  get_stats: function(uri, callback) {
    request({ uri: uri }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('Error when contacting ' + uri);
      }

      jsdom.env({
        html: body,
        scripts: [
          'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'
        ]
      }, function (err, window) {
        // User jQuery to Gather some stats from the connectioncounts HTTP
        // provider.
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        Collector.stats['WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_CURRENT'] = parseInt($('ConnectionsCurrent').html());
        Collector.stats['WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_TOTAL'] = parseInt($('ConnectionsTotal').html());
        Collector.stats['WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_IN'] = parseFloat($('MessagesInBytesRate').html());
        Collector.stats['WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_OUT'] = parseFloat($('MessagesOutBytesRate').html());
        callback(window);
      });
    });
  },
 }

/**
 * Wrap Collector.get_stats call in a closure it works better with setInterval.
 */
var callDelay = function() {
  Collector.get_stats(argv.uri, function(response) {
    // Print out collected stats.
    console.log(Collector.stats);
  });
}

// Get stats once right away.
callDelay();

// Allo repeating at specified interval if --repeat is set.
if (argv.repeat != undefined) {
  // Default to every 30 seconds if no delay is specified.
  if (argv.delay == undefined) {
    argv.delay = 30000;
  }
  setInterval(callDelay, argv.delay);
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I achieved the output i needed by changing the output section of the code link so.

```
// Print out collected stats.
    //console.log(Collector.stats);
    console.log('WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_CURRENT ' + Collector.stats.WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_CURRENT + ' Rem-East-v4-Edge-1');
    console.log('WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_TOTAL ' + Collector.stats.WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_TOTAL + ' Rem-East-v4-Edge-1')
    console.log('WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_IN ' + Collector.stats.WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_IN + ' Rem-East-v4-Edge-1')
    console.log('WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_OUT ' + Collector.stats.WOWZA_CONNECTIONS_BYTES_OUT + ' Rem-East-v4-Edge-1')
```

Comment: I'm amazed that you managed to write above code yet don't know how to format your ouput.

Comment: It's not my code. The code is from a project someone else worked on, but no longer works here.  I'm not proficient in this code language, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: what you need is [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) your JSON string, then on the object loop through the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I'll toss you a bone - you need to be looking at the line commented `// Print out collected stats.`.  Javascript isn't complicated, I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to interact with your variable and output your data as a properly formatted string.

Comment: I love how the community here down votes just because a novice that wants to learn is asking a basic or incorrectly formatted question. I thought this community fostered learning and developing programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to parse this as JSON, it is already there in an object. Just construct a string the way you want it by accessing it via `Collector.stats`.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple.  I updated my Question to reflect the advise you gave me.